# Infinite yields from an iterator

Tags: ruby, iterator, infinite

I'm trying to learn some ruby.
Imagine I'm looping and doing a long running process, and in this process I want to get a spinner for as long as necessary.

So I could do:

```
a=['|','/','-','\\']
aNow=0
# ... skip setup a big loop
print a[aNow]
aNow += 1
aNow = 0 if aNow == a.length
# ... do next step of process
print "\b"
```

But I thought it'd be cleaner to do:

```
def spinChar
  a=['|','/','-','\\']
  a.cycle{|x| yield x}
end
# ... skip setup a big loop
print spinChar
# ... do next step of process
print "\b"
```

Of course the spinChar call wants a block. If I give it a block it'll hang indefinitely.

How can I get just the next yeild of this block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby's [`yield`](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/tut_containers.html#UD) does not work in the way your example would like. But this might be a good place for a [closure](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/tut_containers.html#UG):

```
def spinner()
  state = ['|','/','-','\\']
  return proc { state.push(state.shift)[0] }
end

spin = spinner

# start working
print spin.call
# more work
print spin.call
# etc...
```

In practice I think this solution might be too "clever" for its own good, but understanding the idea of [`Proc`](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/ref_c_proc.html)s could be useful anyhow.

Answer (score 5):

I like all these suggestions, but I found the Generator in the standard library, and I think it's more along the lines of what I wanted to do:

```
spinChar=Generator.new{ |g|
  ['|','/','-','\\'].cycle{ |x|
    g.yield x
  }
}
#then
spinChar.next
#will indefinitly output the next character.
```

Plain `array index` increments with modulus on a frozen array seems to be fastest.

Vlad's thread is nifty but not exactly what I wanted. And in `spinner class` the one-line increment would be nicer if Ruby supported `i++` like `GLYPHS[@i++%GLYPHS.length]`

Max's `spinner closure` with push shift seems a little intensive to me, but the resulting syntax is almost exactly like this Generator. At least I think that's a closure with proc in there.

Chuck's `with_spinner` is actually pretty close to what I wanted, but why break if you don't have to with a Generator as above.

Vadim, thanks for pointing out the `generator` would be slow.

```
"Here's a test of 50,000 spins:"
                   user       system     total       real
"array index"      0.050000   0.000000   0.050000 (  0.055520)
"spinner class"    0.100000   0.010000   0.110000 (  0.105594)
"spinner closure"  0.080000   0.030000   0.110000 (  0.116068)
"with_spinner"     0.070000   0.030000   0.100000 (  0.095915)
"generator"        6.710000   0.320000   7.030000 (  7.304569)
```

Comment: Generators are painfully slow. Ruby 1.9 has Fibers which could do roughly the same but fast.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14894334/1698467 - what name of this solution? `spinner closure` ?

Answer (score 5):

I think you were on the right track with `cycle`. How about something like this:

```
1.8.7 :001 > spinner = ['|','/','-','\\'].cycle
 => #<Enumerable::Enumerator:0x7f111c165790> 
1.8.7 :002 > spinner.next
 => "|" 
1.8.7 :003 > spinner.next
 => "/" 
1.8.7 :004 > spinner.next
 => "-" 
1.8.7 :005 > spinner.next
 => "\\" 
1.8.7 :006 > spinner.next
 => "|"
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you quite understand what `yield` does in Ruby. It doesn't return a value from a block — it passes a value *to* the block you've passed to the enclosing method.

I think you want something more like this:

```
def with_spinner
  a=['|','/','-','\\']
  a.cycle do |x|
    print x
    $stdout.flush # needed because standard out is usually buffered
    yield # this will call the do-block you pass to with_spinner
  end
end

with_spinner do
  #process here
  #break when done
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit inside-out, if you'll pardon me saying so. :)

Why not:

```
class Spinner
  GLYPHS=['|','/','-','\\']
  def budge
    print "#{GLYPHS[@idx = ((@idx || 0) + 1) % GLYPHS.length]}\b"
  end
end

spinner = Spinner.new
spinner.budge
# do something
spinner.budge
spinner.budge
# do something else
spinner.budge
```

**Now**, if you want something like:

```
with_spinner do
  # do my big task here
end
```

...then you'd have to **use multi-threading**:

```
def with_spinner
  t = Thread.new do
    ['|','/','-','\\'].cycle { |c| print "#{c}\b" ; sleep(1) }
  end
  yield
  Thread.kill(t) # nasty but effective
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time, I wrote an array. But it's not just an array, it's an array that has a pointer, so you can call next foreverrr!
http://gist.github.com/55955

Pair this class with a simple iterator or loop and you are golden.

```
 a = Collection.new(:a, :b, :c)
 1000.times do |i|
   puts a.current
   a.next
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

hehe, the answer above mine is all dirty.

```
a=['|','/','-','\\']
a << a
a.each {|item| puts item}
```