# Get output of pv using python

Tags: python, subprocess

Is there a way to use the program pv from within python so as to get the progress of an operation?

So far I have the following:

```
    p0 = sp.Popen(["pv", "-f", args.filepath],
                  bufsize=0,
                  stdout=sp.PIPE,
                  stderr=sp.PIPE)
    p1 = sp.Popen(["awk", "{print $1, $2, $1, $3, $4 }",  "{}".format(args.filepath)],
                   stdout=sp.PIPE,
                   stdin=p0.stdout)
```

But I'm having trouble getting continuous output from `p0`. I tried:

```
    for line in p0.stderr:
        print("line:", line)
```

But this waits for the process to finish and then only prints the last progress report from `pv`. Does anybody know how I can get it to print the continuously updating status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out `pv` outputs each line with a carriage return at end (`\r`). To be able to continuously read from the output, `Popen` needs to be initialized with `universal_lines=True`, like this:

```
    p0 = sp.Popen(['pv', '-f', args.filepath],
                    stdout=sp.PIPE,
                    stderr=sp.PIPE,
                    universal_newlines=True)
```

This leads to a continuous output of progress reports:

```
line: 7.12MB 0:00:01 [ 7.1MB/s] [=>                                  ]  8% ETA 0:00:11

line: 14.6MB 0:00:02 [7.42MB/s] [====>                               ] 16% ETA 0:00:10

line: 22.1MB 0:00:03 [7.55MB/s] [=======>                            ] 24% ETA 0:00:09

line: 29.5MB 0:00:04 [7.36MB/s] [==========>                         ] 33% ETA 0:00:08
```

Here's a reference to a similar question:

[Real time output of subprocess.popen() and not line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620547/real-time-output-of-subprocess-popen-and-not-line-by-line)

Comment: The other key takeaway, that I missed at first, is the `-f / --force` option to `pv`. Otherwise it won't output the status when the shell isn't a terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

try reading from p0.stderr

pv leaves stdout untouched, it writes only to stderr

Comment: That's what I'm trying (see the second code block in my post) .