# Getting pv output with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, pv

I am writing a script to automate database imports in MySQL. I'm trying to write code that displays the output of `pv` as the database is imported:

```
    pv = subprocess.Popen(
        ["pv", "-f", restore_filepath],
        bufsize=1,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        universal_newlines=True,
        shell=True,
    )
    subprocess.Popen(
        [
            "mysql",
            "-u{}".format(db_user),
            "-p{}".format(db_pass),
            db_name,
        ],
        shell=True,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
        stdin=pv.stdout,
    )
    for line in pv.stderr:
        print("hello")
        sys.stdout.write("\r" + line.rstrip("\n"))
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

This is based on the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39274976/get-output-of-pv-using-python/39292586), but it is not working for me. The `hello` never even gets printed, even if I comment out the other lines in the for loop - `for line in pv.stderr` is blocking and I don't know why. It never unblocks, so even once the process has completed, the program is still stuck - I have to kill it.

What am I doing wrong that is causing `for line in pv.stderr` to block?

Comment: What’s with the second `Popen` that is discarded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[When shell=True](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/a-trap-of-shell-true-in-the-subprocess-module-6db7fc66cdfd), `args[0]` is the command to be executed and `args[1:]` are arguments passed to `sh`. You want `-p` and `restore_filepath` to be passed to `pv` not `sh`. So use `shell=False`. The same goes for your other `subprocess.Popen` call.

Since with `shell=True`,`pv` is not receiving any arguments, so it is  hanging because it was still waiting for a filename. So again, the solution is to use `shell=False`.

Also note when [replacing a shell pipeline](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline), you should close `stdout` on the first process to allow it to receive SIGPIPE if the second process exists. This allows some programs (those that handle SIGPIPE) to more gracefully exit if the pipeline is broken.

```
pv = subprocess.Popen(
    ["pv", "-f", restore_filepath],
    shell=False,  # optional, since this is the default
    bufsize=1,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    universal_newlines=True,
)
mysql = subprocess.Popen(
    ["mysql",
     "-u{}".format(db_user),
     "-p{}".format(db_pass),
     db_name],
    shell=False,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
    stdin=pv.stdout,
)
pv.stdout.close() # Allow pv to receive a SIGPIPE if mysql exits. 
for line in pv.stderr:
    print("hello")
    sys.stdout.write("\r" + line.rstrip("\n"))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```