# Why is Python subprocess not working as expected with named_pipe?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, subprocess, pipe, pv

I am using python subprocess to run a mysqlimport command. For tracking the uploading progress, I am using a named pipe and pipe_viewer.
Here is another similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53981907/getting-pv-output-with-subprocess).

The subprocess Pipes are running without any error, but mysqlimport command is not uploading data to the required table.

```py
import subprocess, os, sys
os.mkfifo('named_pipe')
pv = subprocess.Popen(
    ["pv", "-f", "file.csv", ">", "named_pipe"],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
)
pro = subprocess.Popen(
["mysqlimport", "--ignore-lines=1", "--fields-terminated-by=\',\'", 
"--local", "-u", "root", "-pRoot@123", "database_name", named_pipe],
stdin=pv.stdout,
)

pv.stdout.close()
```

This is the simple mysqlimport command which is running fine and uploading data but without pipe_viewer, the progress can not be tracked:

```
pro = subprocess.Popen(
["mysqlimport", "--ignore-lines=1", "--fields-terminated-by=\',\'",
 "--local", "-u", "root", "-pRoot@123", "database_name", "file.csv"], 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)
```

Here is the terminal command using pipe_viewer and mysqlimport which is working fine:

```
$ mkfifo named_pipe

$ pv -f file.csv > named_pipe | mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=',' --local -u root -pRoot@123 database_name named_pipe
```

Comment: Tip: for managing the pipes/ques better use https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues

Comment: Which part of the code is this in reference to?

Answer (score 1):

To get the ">" redirection to work correctly, you most likely need to set "shell=True" to the Popen function.

Comment: Hi Daid, I set shell=True in the first subprocess but still no progress.


Also, this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53982050/12045568) tells otherwise.

Please see if you can find any other loophole in the code.