# print that only prints one line

Tags: python

How would you make print only print one line each time like

```
for i in range(1,100)
    print i
```

but then i would want it to print one line each time so it would be: 1 and then 1 would be erased then it would print 2 and so on.

Comment: Related: [in-place-progress-output-in-the-terminal-or-console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336474/in-place-progress-output-in-the-terminal-or-console/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

```
import sys
import time
>>> for i in range(1, 100):
...     sys.stdout.write(str(i))
...     sys.stdout.flush()
...     time.sleep(0.2)
...     sys.stdout.write("\b"*4)
<numbers count here>
>>>
```

Comment: Oh, idk if this would work on windows, and it is cleaner to use "\r" over printing backspaces.  On linux if you don't flush the buffer, you don't see anything until the loops ends.

Comment: Argh, I was just about to post that. I was going to use `chr(8)` though -- I forgot that `\b` does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

A trailing comma suppresses the newline, a carriage return moves to the beginning of the line.

```
for i in range(1,100):
    print "\r",i,
```

This works on Linux.

Comment: It also works for me on Windows (in the interactive Python 2.6 shell, anyway).

Comment: It doesn't work for me (Ubuntu 10.10) as the output is not flushed to the screen (this generally only happens when a newline is printed, execution finished or it is explicitly flushed). You need to use ``sys.stdout.flush()`` to make sure the output appears, as in [tMC's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827000/print-that-only-prints-one-line/5827046#5827046)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
import sys
import time
for num in range(100):
    sys.stdout.write("\r "+str(num))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your platform.  If the curses module is available to you, use that.  If you're on Windows, and using a sufficiently old version of Python (2.6 and earlier), you could try Fredrik Lundh's [Console](http://effbot.org/zone/console-index.htm).

Comment: @salks:  See my edit, though I think other people have offered better answers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are looking for a progress bar. If so check out some [ready-made ones](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar/2.2).

Even if you are not making a progress bar, the code therein would need to do something similar. Perhaps it can give you some clues.

As I am not a python guy, I don't know the python syntax. For Perl you can add a `\r` character to an interpolated quotation, this moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line, thus overwriting any previous text on the next iteration. Perhaps python has a similar character.

```
perl -e 'print "$_\r" for (1..100); print "\n";'
```

Comment: Ive already made a progress bar i just need to know this one part. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use the backspace character `\b` like

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys, time

for i in range(1, 100):
  print('\b\b\b%d' % i, end='')
  sys.stdout.flush()
  time.sleep(0.1)
```