# How to make console output fixed in place

Tags: c, console, curses

My LAME (v3.99.5) outputs progress in console by moving up x lines in the console and overwriting the previous lines. It's pretty cool.

I've read in a [different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336474/in-place-progress-output-in-the-terminal-or-console) that such behavior for a single line can be achieved with a mere `"\r"` instead of `"\n"` - although the post was for Ruby, it seems to be the same for **C** on my system at least:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

    time_t t;
    time_t t2;

    time(&t);
    t2 = t;

    printf("%u\r", (unsigned int)t);        
    fflush(stdout);

    while (1) {
        if (t2 - t > 0) {
            time(&t);
            printf("%u\r", (unsigned int)t);        
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        time(&t2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The post further suggests a [curses library](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) can be used to make the same behavior multi-line.

What would be a boilerplate example of such code in **C**?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://falsinsoft.blogspot.com/2014/05/set-console-cursor-position-in-windows.html

Windows:

```
void SetCursorPos(int XPos, int YPos)
{
    COORD Coord;
    Coord.X = XPos;
    Coord.Y = YPos;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), Coord);
}
```

Linux:

```
void SetCursorPos(int XPos, int YPos)
{
    printf("\033[%d;%dH", YPos+1, XPos+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

/!\ Warning: If you stop your curses program without call `endwin()` before, the terminal used to launch the program will have a very strange behavior.

```
include <curses.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    // init curses
    Xinitscr(argc, argv); 

    // init time
    time_t t = 0, t2;
    time(&t2);

    // main loop
    while (1) {
        if (t2 - t > 0) 
        {
            time(&t);

            clear();
            mvprintw(1,1, "%u", (unsigned int)t);
            refresh();
        }
        time(&t2);

    }

    // end curses mode
    // warning: if you do not call this at the end of your program,
    // your terminal won't be usable.
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example shown by @purplepsycho has some issues, addressed in this revision (works with "any" X/Open Curses implementation):

```
#include <curses.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    filter();
    initscr();

    // init time
    time_t t = 0, t2;
    time(&t2);

    // main loop
    while (1) {
        if (t2 - t > 0) 
        {
            time(&t);

            erase();
            mvprintw(1,1, "%u", (unsigned int)t);
            refresh();
        }
        time(&t2);

    }
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

That is:

- use [`initscr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-initscr) for initializing curses ([PDCurses](https://github.com/macton/pdcurses/blob/master/pdcurses/initscr.c) provides a non-standard function `Xinitscr` which is not what OP had in mind: it certainly is not often used).
- use [`erase`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_clear.3x.html) rather than `clear` (to avoid screen-flicker):

  > The  **`clear`**  and **`wclear`** routines are like **`erase`** and **`werase`**,
  >   but they also call **`clearok`**, so that the screen is  cleared
  >   completely  on  the  next call to **`wrefresh`** for that window
  >   and repainted from scratch.
- use [`filter`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-filter_nofilter) to keep the output on a single line.  
  If your terminal switches to the alternate screen, the screen will appear to be cleared.  There is a workaround available with ncurses (see [`filter.c`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/test/filter.c) in [ncurses-examples](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html)).

Better than `erase()` would be `wclrtoeol()`, called after the `mvprintw`.